# No package community-mysql-devel available

Tags: centos, yum, mysql, scientific-linux

I'm trying to get this package because I need it to build software on CentOS 6, but I'm getting this error:

```
No package community-mysql-devel available
```

I'm logged in as root, using `yum`.

Could it be because I installed this from a non-net install CD?

I had the same problem with Scientific Linux 6 (non-net CD)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package name should be `mysql-devel`.

And yes, it is the development headers of the community edition of MySQL database.

Comment: This works thank you, Would you happen to know if the repo source thing is also affecting cmake? I'm trying to get the latest version but when I use `yum` to get it I install an older version

Comment: @Dominique If `yum` installs an old version, then it is. Perhaps try to compile cmake from source code?

Comment: I will do that then, or try to add a new repo, do you know a good one? Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 0):

Just a heads up that Fedora has moved away from using MySQL and now uses [MariaDB](https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/#mirror=jmu) as a drop in replacement for MySQL. The package names will continued to be `mysql-*` but their contents will be MariaDB.

You can migrate away from MySQL on CentOS as well, it's pretty straightforward. There's a tutorial which covers how to if you're interested, it's maintained on the CentOS forums in a topic titled: [[SOLVED] Moving from MySQL to MariaDB](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=42821).

MariaDB maintains their own Yum repositories which you can drop in as to your yum setup.

- https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/#mirror=jmu

Comment: Can I use MariaDB libs with source that was build around MySQL libs?

Comment: @Dominique - yes the project strives to be binary compatible with MySQL.https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-versus-mysql-compatibility/